# How to hide element with AngularJS based on DOM element

Tags: html, angularjs, umbraco

I have an Umbraco setup. And when I edit in the CMS I would like for the "Preview" button to disappear whenever there is not a text-editor present in the DOM.

[image: Example on where Preview button should be visible]

Angular file in localtion `Umbraco/Views/content/edit.html`

```html
<form novalidate name="contentForm"
    ng-controller="Umbraco.Editors.Content.EditController"
    ng-show="loaded"
    ng-submit="save()"
    val-form-manager>

    <umb-panel umb-tabs ng-class="{'editor-breadcrumb': ancestors && ancestors.length > 0}">
        <umb-header tabs="content.tabs">

            <div class="span7">
                <umb-content-name placeholder="@placeholders_entername"
                                  ng-model="content.name" />
            </div>

            <div class="span5">
                <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right umb-btn-toolbar">
                    <div class="btn-group" ng-animate="'fade'" ng-show="formStatus">
                        <p class="btn btn-link umb-status-label">{{formStatus}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <umb-options-menu ng-show="currentNode"
                                      current-node="currentNode"
                                      current-section="{{currentSection}}"> 
                    </umb-options-menu>

                </div>
            </div>
        </umb-header>

        <umb-tab-view>
            <umb-tab id="tab{{tab.id}}" rel="{{tab.id}}" ng-repeat="tab in content.tabs">
                <div class="umb-pane">
                    <umb-property property="property"
                                  ng-repeat="property in tab.properties">
                        <umb-editor model="property"></umb-editor>
                    </umb-property>


                    <div class="umb-tab-buttons" detect-fold ng-class="{'umb-dimmed': busy}">

                        <div class="btn-group" ng-show="listViewPath">
                            <a class="btn" href="#{{listViewPath}}">
                                <localize key="buttons_returnToList">Return to list</localize>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="btn-group" ng-show="!isNew">
                            <a class="btn" ng-click="preview(content)">
                                <localize key="buttons_showPage">Preview page</localize>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="btn-group dropup" ng-if="defaultButton">
                            <!-- primary button -->
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" ng-click="performAction(defaultButton)" prevent-default>
                                <localize key="{{defaultButton.labelKey}}">{{defaultButton.labelKey}}</localize>
                            </a>

                            <a class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-if="subButtons.length > 0">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <a href="#">Return to list</a>

                            <!-- sub buttons -->
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu bottom-up" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" ng-if="subButtons.length > 0">
                                <li ng-repeat="btn in subButtons">
                                    <a href="#" ng-click="performAction(btn)" prevent-default>
                                        <localize key="{{btn.labelKey}}">{{btn.labelKey}}</localize>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </umb-tab>
        </umb-tab-view>


        <ul class="umb-panel-footer-nav nav nav-pills" ng-if="ancestors && ancestors.length > 0">
            <li ng-repeat="ancestor in ancestors">
                <a href="#/content/content/edit/{{ancestor.id}}">{{ancestor.name}}</a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>

    </umb-panel>
</form>
```

I am not certain this is the correct file - but it seems to be the place where the `Preview` button is created.

The question now is. Can I somehow determine with angular if the text editor is active and then if it is, show the `Preview` button next to the `Save and publish`?

Comment: What version of Umbraco is this?

I would suggest finding the directive for `umbEditor` and work out how it determines what field type is what. It will no doubt inspect properties of the `property` object that is passed to it.

You should be able to decipher how it works out when to render a RichText and use that information to add a hide / show rule on the button

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd - v7.3 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following

1) Determine what properties are accessible on the object that is passed through to the `<umb-editor>` directive.

[image]

Digging into the code I can see things like it has a `.view` property. You could inspect this at runtime in the browser console to see what additional properties are available

[image]

2) You can write a rule on the button to show if the collection of fields contains one with a certain property you might have identified

something like this...

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Tyvm :) this helped me understand and figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

I found a second solution I might as well add here. I used the Umbraco Plugin [Backoffice Tweaking](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/collaboration/backoffice-tweaking/).

Here I added this to my `Config\BackofficeTweaking.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Config>
  <Rules>
    <Rule Type="HideButtons" Enabled="true" Names="preview" Users="" UserTypes="" ContentTypes="Omraader,Grund,Udstykning,Indstillinger,Niveau,Oversigt_Mappe,Oversigt,Information_Mappe,Information,Afstande_Mappe,Afstande" Description="" />
  </Rules>
  <Scripts>
    <Script Name="example"></Script>
  </Scripts>
</Config>
```

Here you can also make some scripting or do many other things. The plugin also has a visual editor for Umbraco. Pretty easy to use.